# Post with null value aren't included in the result

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of `Wordpress` posts in a `DESC` looking to the `zoacres_property_price` value which is included in the `postmeta` table, so far I achieved this using the following query:

```
SELECT FROM wpps_posts p
    JOIN wpps_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id 
    JOIN wpps_postmeta pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
    WHERE (( 
        tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ('76') OR
        tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ('63') OR
        tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ('')
    ) OR p.post_title LIKE '%amalfi%')
    AND p.post_type = 'zoacres-property' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND pm.meta_key = 'zoacres_property_price'
    ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NULL THEN p.post_title END) DESC,
    (CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL THEN pm.meta_value+0 END) DESC
```

The problem is that some `posts` doesn't contain the `zoacres_property_price` meta, so I tried to return that post using:

```
(CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NULL THEN p.post_title END) DESC
```

but I guess the problem is here:

```
AND pm.meta_key = 'zoacres_property_price'
```

is there a way to return also the posts without `zoacres_property_price`?

**TABLE EXAMPLE**

POSTS:

```
 ID | post_title |
  5      hello
  6      world
```

POSTMETA:

```
 meta_id | post_id | meta_key                 | meta_value
    2         5       zoacres_property_price     10000
```

notice that `meta_value` is `longtext`, that's why I used `pm.meta_value+0`

Expected result  5 - 6, current: 5

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly you want to return result regardless of the pm.meta_key = 'zoacres_property_price'? If so, just remove that line from the where clause

Comment: @ChrisCarroll If I do so all the posts of `Wordpress` are returned, also the posts which doesn't match the `zoacres-property` type

Comment: In your question you asked: "is there a way to return also the posts without zoacres_property_price?", you still have a clause to match p.post_type = 'zoacres-property' in the row above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `LEFT JOIN`.  That requires rearranging some of the logic:

```
SELECT . . 
FROM wpps_posts p JOIN
     wpps_term_relationships tr
     ON p.ID = tr.object_id LEFT JOIN
     wpps_postmeta pm
     ON pm.post_id = p.id AND
        pm.meta_key = 'zoacres_property_price'
WHERE (tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ('76', '63', '') OR
       p.post_title LIKE '%amalfi%')
      ) AND
      p.post_type = 'zoacres-property' AND
      p.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NULL THEN p.post_title END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL THEN pm.meta_value+0 END) DESC;
```

Comment: Hi, this is working, may I could if is possible return to last the posts that doesn't have `pm.meta_value`? I tried using `(CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NULL THEN p.post_title END) ASC,` but the posts doesn't appear

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . Do you want `order by (pm.meta_value is not null) desc`?  That will put the rows with a value first.

Comment: Should I change the case conditions order? 'cause if I replace all the cases with `order by (pm.meta_value is not null) desc` I lost the order for prices to desc

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . You have to put the `order by` keys in the order that you want them.  If you can't figure it out, then ask a new question that is specifically about ordering, because this question is about getting the right rows.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want a `left join`. Consider:

```
SELECT ...
FROM wpps_posts p
INNER JOIN wpps_term_relationships tr 
    ON  p.ID = tr.object_id 
LEFT JOIN wpps_postmeta pm 
    ON  p.id = pm.post_id
    AND pm.meta_key = 'zoacres_property_price'
    WHERE 
        (tr.term_taxonomy_id IN ('76', '63', '') OR p.post_title LIKE '%amalfi%')
        AND p.post_type = 'zoacres-property' 
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY 
        (CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NULL THEN p.post_title END) DESC,
        (CASE WHEN pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL THEN pm.meta_value+0 END) DESC
```

Notes:

- for this to work you need to move the conditions on the `left join`ed table (`pm`) from the `where` clause to the `on` part of the `left join`
- you are missing *something* in the `SELECT` clause
- I simplified the expression that uses `IN`